# How to apply a kernel to a raster image

Tags: image-processing

Im trying to apply a Sharpen Kernel to a raster picture, Here is my kernel:

```
  { 0.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
    -1.0f,5.0f,-1.0f,
    0.0f,-1.0f,0.0f }
```

And here is my Code:

```
struct Pixel{
    GLubyte R, G, B;
    float x, y;
};
. . . 

for (unsigned i = 1; i < iWidth - 1; i++){
            for (unsigned j = 1; j < iHeight - 1; j++){
                float r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
                r += -(float)pixels[i + 1][j].R;
                g += -(float)pixels[i + 1][j].G;
                b += -(float)pixels[i + 1][j].B;

                r += -(float)pixels[i - 1][j].R;
                g += -(float)pixels[i - 1][j].G;
                b += -(float)pixels[i - 1][j].B;

                r += -(float)pixels[i][j + 1].R;
                g += -(float)pixels[i][j + 1].G;
                b += -(float)pixels[i][j + 1].B;

                r += -(float)pixels[i][j - 1].R;
                g += -(float)pixels[i][j - 1].G;
                b += -(float)pixels[i][j - 1].B;

                pixels[i][j].R = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + r);
                pixels[i][j].G = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].G * 5) + g);
                pixels[i][j].B = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].B * 5) + b);

            }
        }
```

But the colors get mixed up when I apply this kernel, Here is an example:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE :** I know that OpenGL can do this fast and easy, but I just wanted to experiment on this kind of masks.

**EDIT :** The first code had a bug:

```
            pixels[i][j].R = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + r);
            pixels[i][j].G = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R/*G*/ * 5) + g);
            pixels[i][j].B = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R/*B*/ * 5) + b);
```

I fixed it but I still got that problem.

Iv changed the last three lines to this:

```
                 r = (float)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + r);
                 g = (float)((pixels[i][j].G * 5) + g);
                 b = (float)((pixels[i][j].B * 5) + b);
                 if (r < 0) r = 0;
                 if (g < 0) g = 0;
                 if (b < 0) b = 0;
                 if (r > 255) r = 255;
                 if (g > 255) g = 255;
                 if (b > 255) b = 255;

                pixels[i][j].R = r;
                pixels[i][j].G = g;
                pixels[i][j].B = b;
```

And now the output looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a copy-paste bug here:

```
            pixels[i][j].R = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + r);
            pixels[i][j].G = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + g);
            pixels[i][j].B = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + b);
                                                     ^
```

This should be:

```
            pixels[i][j].R = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].R * 5) + r);
            pixels[i][j].G = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].G * 5) + g);
            pixels[i][j].B = (GLubyte)((pixels[i][j].B * 5) + b);
```

Also it looks like you may have `iWidth`/`iHeight` transposed, but it's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. Typically though the outer loop iterates over rows, so the upper bound would be the number of rows, i.e. the image height.

Most importantly though you have a fundamental problem in that you're trying to perform a neighbourhood operation in-place. Each output pixel depends on its neighbours, but you're modifying these neighbours as you iterate through the image. You need to do this kind of operation out-of-place, i.e. have a separate output image:

```
            out_pixels[i][j].R = r;
            out_pixels[i][j].G = g;
            out_pixels[i][j].B = b;
```

so that the input image does not get modified. (Note also that you'll want to copy the edge pixels over from the input image to the output image.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I fixed that Bug but I still have the same problem. What part of the code do you need?

Comment: Did you address the issue of height versus width ?

Comment: See also the final paragraph about in-place neighbourhood operations.

Comment: "Most importantly though you have a fundamental problem in that you're trying to perform a neighbourhood operation in-place". Yeah that was my problem, Thnk you